How to display dynamic images in React Native
I tried using dynamic images in 'react native'. But there has been a error in that method. How to solve this?
The below code snippet works fine.
const image = require('./path/to/home.jpg');   
return (     
    <View>      
        <Image source={image}>     
    </View>   
);

But if I change it to a dynamic string,
const image = require({img});   
return (     
    <View>      
        <Image source={image}>    
    </View>   
);

Then I get an error. So how to display dynamic images in React Native.

What are you passing to require in this example

Could you log "img" result? console.log(img); is it ./path/to/home.jpg or not?

React Native doesn't supports dynamic imports as long as metro is involved. You need to write out a full require path.
See this discussion for more details
